# How can I calculate the standard deviation and mean across rows of various columns?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation across all rows for the columns that start with  `Sum of EBIT [CY 2]`. I was able to calculate the mean, by adding the 10 columns and dividing it by 10.

**As can be seen below:**

```
pub fn industry_beta_f(raw_data:DataFrame, marginal_tax_rate:Expr) -> DataFrame{

    let df = raw_data.clone().lazy()
                                .with_columns([
                                    ((col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2011] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2012] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2013] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2014] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2015] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2016] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2017] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2018] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2019] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2020] ($USDmm, Historical rate)")) / lit(10.0)).alias("moments_mean"),
                                    (col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2011] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2012] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2013] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2014] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2015] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2016] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2017] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2018] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2019] ($USDmm, Historical rate)") + col("Sum of EBIT [CY 2020] ($USDmm, Historical rate)")).std(1).alias("moments_std"),

                                ])
                                .with_columns([
                                    when(col("moments_mean").gt(lit(0.0)))
                                    .then(col("moments_std") / col("moments_mean"))
                                    .otherwise(f64::NAN)
                                    .alias("Standard deviation in operating income (last 10 years)")
                                ])
                                .select([col("Industry Name"),
                                        col("Number of firms"),
                                        col("Standard deviation in operating income (last 10 years)")])
                                .collect()
                                .unwrap();
    return df
}
```

I am having trouble calculating the standard deviation across all the rows for the columns that start with `Sum of EBIT [CY 2]`. Because using the `std()` formula, it calculates the std for each column instead of across the rows.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTr1H.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m9y8.png)

There is a huge gap between the two outputs. Since, for the current output the `std` is calculated across the column, and for the expected output the `std` is calculated across the rows.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the mean using the built-in `mean_horizontal` method of a DataFrame.

The standard deviation is not supported out-of-the-box, and therefore a bit trickier. You first calculate the mean, then the sum of squared errors, and then divide it by the number of columns - 1, as follows:

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() -> PolarsResult<()> {
    let mut df = df! (
        "col_1" => &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "col_2" => &[2, 4, 6, 8, 5],
        "col_3" => &[10, 8, 6, 4, 5],
    )?;

    let n = df.get_column_names().len() as i32;

    let col_mean = df.mean_horizontal(polars::frame::NullStrategy::Ignore)?;

    let df_w_mean: &mut DataFrame;
    if let Some(mean) = col_mean {
        df_w_mean = df.with_column(mean.with_name("col_mean"))?;
    } else {
        return Err(PolarsError::ComputeError("No mean can be calculated".into()));
    }
    
    let sse = df_w_mean
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .with_column((col("*") - col("col_mean")).pow(2))
        .collect()?
        .sum_horizontal(polars::frame::NullStrategy::Ignore)?;
    
    let df_w_sse: &mut DataFrame;
    if let Some(sse) = sse {
        df_w_sse = df_w_mean.with_column(sse.with_name("col_std"))?;
    } else {
        return Err(PolarsError::ComputeError("No sse can be caculated".into()));
    }

    let result = df_w_sse.clone().lazy().with_column((col("col_std") / lit(n - 1)).sqrt()).collect()?;
    println!("{:?}", result);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I tried using the ```mean_horizontal()``` and ```sum_horizontal``` but it didn't work for my scenario. Is there a neater way to solve the problem?

Comment: If you tried something, and it didn't work, it would be great to include that (and the observed behaviour or issues you had with that approach) in your question. Also, "neater" is highly subjective, and it is unclear to me what you have in mind.